# TabControl Header's Height

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, size, tabcontrol

I am working with WinForms and at a point I am unable to find the height of Header of TabControl user in my Win-form,
Below I am attaching the In-circle Image which i want to achieve, I have searched a lot but I am unable to find out solution

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: It is completely unclear why you need to solve this problem.  It has multiple answers.  You'd get somewhere by using the PointToScreen(Point.Empty) method on the tab control, that gives the upper left corner of the tab control.  And subtract the same you'd get from the TabPage.  Or the tab rectangle.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: I had to find out the page starting area , that's why I have asked,It was clear in screen-shot.

Comment: Hard to believe you like the answer, it includes the padding between the bottom of the tab page and the bottom of the tab control.  Finding the tabpage back should never be difficult.  The standard problem with a screenshot, nobody can see it.

Comment: @Hans Pasant: Buddy I had to find out the Header's Size, which I got from the below code, So Its enough for me.

Comment: I have attached picture, I guess some contents blocking at admin side, which bared my image to upload, I will upload fresh image from other site, thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way

```
TabControl1.ItemSize.Height
```

Answer (score 7):

write this way:

that can find your headser height.

```
TabControl1.Height - TabPage1.Height
```

Comment: Funny thing that noone from dx team couldn't simply answer the similar question asked at their forum, while the solution was as simple as that.